# How do I authenticate using MSXML2.XMLHTTP and VBA?

Tags: vba, http, web-scraping, request

I need to authenticate on the endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children` using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and VBA.

I have the access token already but I am struggling to find out the string to be used on:

`setRequestHeader` method.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you checked [any web page describing this topic](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)? You should probably explain better the "struggling" part... where is your code, and what doesn't work?

Comment: I found it here:

Comment: Or even https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching I found the solution:

`setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken`

Comment: remember after 2 days you can accept your own answer. It would also be beneficial if you added your code (without the above solution line) to the original question using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55767687/edit)